# My app is blocked by Smart manager. Any idea for resolving it?

Tags: java, android

Need some help here.
I've built this app which scan the device for vulnerabilities.
This app is not on Google play store.
When I get it tested by other, ironically it gets a warning alert as below.
Is there a way to get around it?

[image]

Comment: Hit **`INSTALL`**

Answer (score 0):

Google is having it's own play protect system to flag specific apps functioning with root access so if your app is having some root access or is performing any operations over the operating system then your app may get flagged as a threat.

This can be removed in Google Settings.

Open Settings.
Select "Google" (if there is no "Google", open Google Settings from your launcher).
Select "Security".
Select "Google Play Protect".
Turn off "Scan device for security threats".

Comment: Is there a work around which can be performed in the code of the app?